# Search for a record else create a new record

Tags: apex, order-of-execution

I have a before insert handler class, that based on criteria tries to find a custom object (responsible party) record with a matching key and then populate a lookup on the OpportunityLineItem. This seems to work great in the sandbox where I am developing and testing as long as there is a record to match against. What I want to add to the logic is that if no match is found I want to create a new responsible party record and attach that to the OLI.

I can't seem to wrap my head around when I should check that a match is not found and then create the record. I'll post my methods that I have for an example that filter, query, then update the OLI. When I go to update the OLI and there is no match do I go off and then create a record and make another method to attach it? Or do I figure out that no match was found before going to the update that way I can create and then match against the map?

```
public without sharing class NPD_Responsible_Party_Locator
{

public static void filterInsert(List<OpportunityLineItem> newList)
{
    List<OpportunityLineItem> olis = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    Set<String> olikeys = new Set<String>();
    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> prodIds = new Set<Id>();

    // Create a set of all the unique Opp Ids that we need to query for
    for(OpportunityLineItem oliO : newList)
        oppIds.add(oliO.OpportunityId);

    // Create a map so that Opportunity is locatable by its Id (key)
    Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(
        [SELECT Id, Account.OwnerId, AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :oppIds]);

    // Create a set of all the unique Product Ids that we need to query for
    for(OpportunityLineItem oliP : newList)
        prodIds.add(oliP.Product2Id);

    // Create a map so that the Product is locatable by its Id (key)
    Map<Id, Product2> prodsMap = new Map<Id, Product2>(
        [SELECT Id, Formula_LOB__c, Practice__c, Practice__r.Key_Type__c FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN :prodIds]);

    // On Insert we add to all products
    for(OpportunityLineItem oppyLine : newList)
    {
        if(prodsMap.get(oppyLine.Product2Id).Practice__r.Key_Type__c == 'Account Owner - Practice')
        {
            olikeys.add(oppsMap.get(oppyLine.OpportunityId).Account.OwnerId + '-' + prodsMap.get(oppyLine.Product2Id).Practice__c);
            olis.add(oppyLine);
        }
        if(prodsMap.get(oppyLine.Product2Id).Practice__r.Key_Type__c == 'Account - Accounting Unit')
        {
            olikeys.add(oppsMap.get(oppyLine.OpportunityId).AccountId + '-' + prodsMap.get(oppyLine.Product2Id).Formula_LOB__c);
            olis.add(oppyLine);
        }
        if(prodsMap.get(oppyLine.Product2Id).Practice__r.Key_Type__c == 'Account - Practice')
        {
            olikeys.add(oppsMap.get(oppyLine.OpportunityId).AccountId + '-' + prodsMap.get(oppyLine.Product2Id).Practice__c);
            olis.add(oppyLine);
        }
    }
    Map<String, Responsible_Party__c> rmap = getResParty(olikeys);
    updateOLI(rmap, olis, oppsMap, prodsMap);
}


public static Map<String, Responsible_Party__c> getResParty(Set<String> olikeys)
{
    Map<String, Responsible_Party__c> rmap = new Map<String, Responsible_Party__c>();

    for(Responsible_Party__c r : [SELECT    Id,
                                            Name,
                                            User__c,
                                            Sector__c,
                                            Key__c
                                  FROM      Responsible_Party__c
                                  WHERE     Key__c IN : olikeys])
    {
        rmap.put(r.Key__c, r);
    }
    return rmap;
}


public static void updateOLI(Map<String, Responsible_Party__c> rmap, List<OpportunityLineItem> olis, Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsMap, Map<Id, Product2> prodsMap)
{
    Responsible_Party__c r = new Responsible_Party__c();

    for(OpportunityLineItem o : olis)
    {
        if(prodsMap.get(o.Product2Id).Practice__r.Key_Type__c == 'Account Owner - Practice')
        {
            r = rmap.get(oppsMap.get(o.OpportunityId).Account.OwnerId + '-' + prodsMap.get(o.Product2Id).Practice__c);
        }
        if(prodsMap.get(o.Product2Id).Practice__r.Key_Type__c == 'Account - Accounting Unit')
        {
            r = rmap.get(oppsMap.get(o.OpportunityId).AccountId + '-' + prodsMap.get(o.Product2Id).Formula_LOB__c);
        }
        if(prodsMap.get(o.Product2Id).Practice__r.Key_Type__c == 'Account - Practice')
        {
            r = rmap.get(oppsMap.get(o.OpportunityId).AccountId + '-' + prodsMap.get(o.Product2Id).Practice__c);
        }

        if(r != null)
        {
            o.Responsible_Party__c = r.Id;
        }
        else{
            o.Responsible_Party__c = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: before insert of which object this handler is called?

Comment: before the opportunitylineitem record is inserted.

Comment: so basically, before OLI insert you are checking if Responsible_Party__c exists. If that record records that, you will put o.Responsible_Party__c, otherwise not. Is that correct?

Comment: Right, but the idea is I want to expand it and if no match exists, create one and then put the new id in o.Responsible_Party__c. I don't know when the create should happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you may need to refactor the `getResParty()` method like this. In this method, you will first search for existing records and put that into the map.

After that, create new records and finally fire an SOQL to fetch newly created records.

so, your returned map will have all records based on `olikeys`. That's it!

```
public static Map<String, Responsible_Party__c> getResParty(Set<String> olikeys)
{
    Map<String, Responsible_Party__c> rmap = new Map<String, Responsible_Party__c>();

    for(Responsible_Party__c r : [SELECT    Id,
                                            Name,
                                            User__c,
                                            Sector__c,
                                            Key__c
                                  FROM      Responsible_Party__c
                                  WHERE     Key__c IN : olikeys])
    {
        rmap.put(r.Key__c, r);
    }

    //if record does not exists then create the record here
    List<Responsible_Party__c> lstNewList = new List<Responsible_Party__c>();
    Set<String> newValueSet = new Set<String>(); //capture Key__c for which records to be created. It will help to fetch newly created records.

    for(String strKey:olikeys)
    {
        if(!rmap.containsKey(strKey))
        {
            Responsible_Party__c newResPartyObj = new Responsible_Party__c();
            newResPartyObj.Key__c = strKey;
            //assign other attributes
            lstNewList.add(newResPartyObj);
            newValueSet.add(strKey);
        }
    }
    insert lstNewList;

    //retrieve newly created values and add this to the map
    for(Responsible_Party__c r : [SELECT    Id,
                                            Name,
                                            User__c,
                                            Sector__c,
                                            Key__c
                                  FROM      Responsible_Party__c
                                  WHERE     Key__c IN : newValueSet])
    {
        rmap.put(r.Key__c, r);
    }

    return rmap;
}
```

Comment: Ohhh I see. this way when you're assigning the records I don't need to touch it as the map has everything that is needed.

Comment: you could change this method based on the need, but this should the logic. Ultimate `rmap` should have all the records at the time of returning. Also in the update method, `o.Responsible_Party__c = null;` is not needed as you will always have `Responsible_Party__c` for OLI

Comment: is my answer worked for you?

Comment: It should I haven't tried it yet because I got tasked with admin things. That's why I haven't accepted. I'll have now and open a new if there's a problem.